# CE-1.8.1.0 Redirect Loop in admin

Tags: redirect

- CE-1.8.1.0
- Windows 2008 R2 Server
- IIS 7.5 Web server

History: We had a perfectly functioning web store UNTIL I added the account of a newly-hired IT person to the Share ACL of the web root. All *^#$%#^ broke loose - all of our websites went down - the cause was many changes to the security ACLs. I hurriedly restored the proper permissions but since then the admin interface to Magento now has an infinite redirect loop.

I have checked all logs for problems, tried clearing the sessions and cache, and even copied the entire file set and database to my workstation (where it works just fine).

Using the "Live HTTP Headers" Firefox plugin I discovered what was happening.

I would paste a block of header info but I am informed that I don't have enough "reputation."

There is an infinite loop of 301 Moved Permanently to the `http://` without the `index.php` (which is wrong -- should be `https://`)

Then 302 Moved Temporarily to the `https://` URL with the `index.php` (which is also wrong since there is a rewrite rule in web.config that is the equivalent to the directives in .htaccess)

Once the browser gives up and informs me about the redirect loop I can edit the URL and get the admin page to load but much of the functionality is lost.

I have even tried a fresh install of Magento but can't get past the license acceptance because -- you guessed it! -- there is a 301 Moved Permanently header sent which drops the little "agree=1" post.

I've done a LOT of Google searching since this started and haven't found any solution.

I am open to any suggestions, and would appreciate any help.

Edit - 2/13/15

After a couple more days troubleshooting I have come to the conclusion that the problem is within the IIS 7.5 web server, not within Magento. Thanks to all who have answered with suggestions.

Comment: sounds like an issue in the .htaccess, Apache vhost configuration or NginX configuration. Did you check those for conflicting rules? I'm 99.999% sure it's not Magento if it happened after a fresh install but just to be sure, the base_url in the database is correct?

Comment: Are you installing in a fresh database? If not, check the values of web/url/redirect_to_base and web/secure/use_in_frontend in the database.  It is under the core_config_data table.

Comment: According to your last update, please answer or else close your own question. Thanks!